# How can I make this as one function?

Tags: javascript, function

I am new in javascript and I am creating an easy game, how can I make this three functions as one please? Thank youuu :)

```js
function create_rat() {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'img/mice.jpg';
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, foodPosX, foodPosY, snakeSize, snakeSize);
}

function create_snake() {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'img/snake.jpg';
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, snakePosX, snakePosY, snakeSize, snakeSize);
}

function create_eagle() {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'img/eagle.jpg';
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, eaglePosX, eaglePosY, snakeSize, snakeSize);
}
```

Comment: Your code is flawed anyway. Who's to say whether your image has loaded yet when you try to draw it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply find the differences and use it as your **function arguments**:

```js
function draw(name, x, y) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, snakeSize, snakeSize);
    img.src = `img/${name}.jpg`;
}

draw("mice", foodPosX, foodPosY);
draw("snake", snakePosX, snakePosY);
draw("eagle", eaglePosX, eaglePosY);
```

Also, make sure to `drawImage` once it's loaded.